# instructions related to parameter passing of variable argument function "printf"

Tags: c, printf

In the program binary, how to determine the instructions related to parameter passing of variable argument function "printf"?   For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int fun(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

void main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    printf("a:fun(b,c):d: %d:%d:%d\n", a, fun(b,c), d);
}
```

is assembled as follows:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483f1 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483f2 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483f4 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080483f7 <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x080483fa <+9>: movl   $0x0,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048402 <+17>:    movl   $0x1,0x14(%esp)
   0x0804840a <+25>:    movl   $0x2,0x18(%esp)
   0x08048412 <+33>:    movl   $0x3,0x1c(%esp)
   0x0804841a <+41>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x0804841e <+45>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048422 <+49>:    mov    0x14(%esp),%eax
   0x08048426 <+53>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048429 <+56>:    call   0x80483e4 <fun>
=> 0x0804842e <+61>:    mov    $0x8048530,%edx
   0x08048433 <+66>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%ecx
   0x08048437 <+70>:    mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp)
   0x0804843b <+74>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x0804843f <+78>:    mov    0x10(%esp),%eax
   0x08048443 <+82>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
=> 0x08048447 <+86>:    mov    %edx,(%esp)
   0x0804844a <+89>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x0804844f <+94>:    leave 
   0x08048450 <+95>:    ret
```

Whether the instructions related to parameter passing of variable argument function "print" are instructions between two instructions "0x0804842e <+61>: mov $0x8048530,%edx" and  " 0x08048447 <+86>: mov %edx,(%esp)".

I have tested many cases of function "printf". In all my tested cases, the instructions related to parameter passing are between these two instructions.

Comment: What is the question? What does "determine the address space" mean?

Comment: What definition of "address space" affords a single process having more than one?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not describe the problem clearly. And I have edit the problem again.

Comment: @unwind In fact, I want to decide the instructions that are related to parameter passing of function "printf"

Comment: You seem to know how to find where the parameters are passed. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking from us ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker In my example program, I know how to find where the parameters are passed. I can determine the positions are between  "0x0804842e <+61>: mov $0x8048530,%edx" and " 0x08048447 <+86>: mov %edx,(%esp)".  But I do not know it is applicable to all situations.

Comment: If you're asking whether it's always gonna be this clear-cut and easy to recognize, then no, that's not the case. Different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) exist (that pass parameters via registers eg.), [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) can re-order instructions and even eliminate them entirely, etc.

Comment: Do you understand that the C language does not specify any particular mechanism for passing a variable argument list to a function?  That's one of the many details left to the discretion of implementations, though in practice it's probably chosen at the ABI level in most environments.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thank you, I feel I have got the answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for providing the information, I'll go to learn the corresponding knowledge such as ABI.

Answer (score -1):

You can find this out by knowing the C calling convention. That is arguments are pushed  onto the stack in reverse order.

`0x0804842e <+61>:    mov    $0x8048530,%edx //Probably the string literal

0x08048433 <+66>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%ecx  //Moving 3 literal into %ecx

0x08048437 <+70>:    mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp) //  moving 3 onto top of the arguments on the stack (%esp is the stack pointer)

0x0804843b <+74>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)  //Moving return value from fun onto next slot in the stack, %eax store the return value from a function.

0x0804843f <+78>:    mov    0x10(%esp),%eax //Moving 0 literal into %eax

0x08048443 <+82>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp) //Moving %eax into next slot in the stack

0x08048447 <+86>:    mov    %edx,(%esp) //moving string literal onto the stack

0x0804844a <+89>:    call   0x8048300 `//calling printf

Comment: The C language standard says nothing about "calling convention" or arguments being "pushed onto the stack". There may not even *be* a stack.

What you have described is *one* implementation's way of doing things.